# H2O Download CSV in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: python, download, h2o, automl, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to build a ML model in Azure Machine Learning using H2o AutoML and could successfully create the model and do prediction.
What I am struggling with is to download the result as csv (ideally to my local PC).

The code I used is :

```
#Predict on the whole dataset
pred = best_model.predict(data)
data_pred = data.cbind(pred)

# Download as csv
h2o.download_csv(data_pred,'data_pred .csv')
```

The above code runs without any error & shows ***'/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/SA/data_pred.csv'*** as the result message. I assume the csv has been created succesfully.

But I don't know where to locate it.
I searched in AzureML datasets but there is none. Appreciate if someone can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be the path that you run your Python file? I'm not familiar with `h2o`, but normally if you don't specify the exact path, the file exports into the path that you compiler your Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2O Documentation says that:

`h2o.h2o.download_csv(data, filename)`

`data : H2OFrame` An H2OFrame object to be downloaded.

`filename : str` A string indicating the name that the CSV file should be should be saved to.

Additionally, as you have written in your question `/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/SA/data_pred.csv'` should be the path.

Comment: Thanks Nijat. I had to go to workspace -> storageexplorer to locate the file. Glad that I could locate it at last.